# Proving that Borel Sigma Algebras are Equal

Tags: measure-theory

I would like some help proving the following result. Thanks for any help in advance.

Prove that $\sigma$({[-$\infty$,x):-$\infty$ < x < $\infty$})= $\sigma$($\mathcal{D}$), where $\mathcal{D}$= {$\mathbb{R}$, {$\infty$}, {-$\infty$}, (-$\infty$, b), [a,b): -$\infty$ $\leq$ a $\leq$ b $\leq$ $\infty$}. Note that $\mathbb{R}$ refers to the extended real numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the best approach for showing that two $\sigma$-algebras are equal is to show that they're subsets of one another - that is, show that the generators of one can be found in the other, and vice versa. For example, $[-\infty,x)$ can be formed from taking $(-\infty,x) \cup \{-\infty\}$ from $\mathcal{D}$. Try coming up with a similar approach for building the generators of $\mathcal{D}$ from the first $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Ah, I see. I knew the strategy, but I misunderstood the definition of D.